# Prove triangle inequality of vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am trying to show that $||x+y||_p \leq ||x||_p + ||y||_p$ where $p$ is an integer larger than 1, but not infinity (I proved those cases already), and $||x||_p = (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

We were also given a hint:

Holder's inequality states $\langle u,w \rangle \leq ||u||_p ||w||_q$ when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ implies $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$ and $\langle u,w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n u_iw_i$

I'd appreciate any help offered here...I already showed its true for $p=1$ and $p= \infty$ as single cases.

Comment: Hint: $$\lvert a+b\rvert^p = \lvert a+b\rvert\cdot\lvert a+b\rvert^{p-1} \leqslant \lvert a\rvert\cdot \lvert a+b\rvert^{p-1} + \lvert b\rvert\cdot \lvert a+b\rvert^{p-1}.$$

Comment: after repeating the process that you suggested $p$ times, I arrive at : $||x+y||_p \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n (|x_i|+|y_i|)^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Comment: No, you don't repeat it (and $p$ is not an integer in general). Take it as it is, and throw Hölder's inequality at it.

Comment: Could you explain how I use holders inequality on this? I don't understand where $q$ is coming from. for example $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i||x_i+y_i|^{p-1}$, we can look at it as $\langle u, w \rangle$ when $u_i=|x_i|$ and $w_i = |x_i+y_i|^{p-1}$, so according to holder that will be smaller than $||u||_p ||w||_q$ but what are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: You're practically there. $p$ is $p$, and $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$. Now, what is $\lVert w\rVert_q$ with $w$ as above?

Comment: If i am not mistaken, it is $(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i+y_i|^p)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}$

Comment: Right. And do you see how you can express that in a different way, related to the task?

Comment: I don't see any way to rewrite this,only thing that comes to mind is using the triangle inequality again like we did in the beginning but i dont think that will get us anywhere.

Comment: We could rewrite it as $|x_1+y_1|^{p-1}+(\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}|x_i+y_i|^p)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+|x_n+y_n|^{p-1}$ using newton's binomial...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the cases $p = 1$ and $p = \infty$ are already done, I treat only $1 < p < \infty$.

For arbitrary $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, we have

$$\lvert a+b\rvert^p = \lvert a+b\rvert\cdot\lvert a+b\rvert^{p-1} \leqslant \lvert a\rvert\cdot\lvert a+b\rvert^{p-1} + \lvert b\rvert\cdot \lvert a+b\rvert^{p-1}.$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}
\lVert x+y\rVert_p^p &= \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i + y_i\rvert^p\\
&\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{\lvert x_i\rvert}_{u_i}\cdot \underbrace{\lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^{p-1}}_{w_i} + \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{\lvert y_i\rvert}_{u_i} \cdot \underbrace{\lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^{p-1}}_{w_i}.
\end{align}$$

Applying Hölder's inequality with $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$ to each of the last sums, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\lVert x+y\rVert_p^p &\leqslant \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i\rvert^p\right)^{1/p} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^{p-1}\right)^{p/(p-1)}\right)^{(p-1)/p}\\
&\qquad + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert y_i\rvert^p\right)^{1/p} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^{p-1}\right)^{p/(p-1)}\right)^{(p-1)/p}\\
&= \lVert x\rVert_p \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^p\right)^{(p-1)/p}
+ \lVert y\rVert_p \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^p\right)^{(p-1)/p}\\
&= \lVert x\rVert_p \lVert x+y\rVert_p^{p-1} + \lVert y\rVert_p\lVert x+y\rVert_p^{p-1}\\
&= \left(\lVert x\rVert_p + \lVert y\rVert_p\right) \cdot\lVert x+y\rVert_p^{p-1}.
\end{align}$$

Now, either $\lVert x+y\rVert_p = 0$, in which case the inequality $\lVert x+y\rVert_p \leqslant \lVert x\rVert_p + \lVert y\rVert_p$ trivially holds, or we can divide the last inequality we obtained by $\lVert x+y\rVert_p^{p-1}$ to obtain the desired triangle inequality.